# SQL query to identify the same customer across multiple rows using emails and ensure the output rows have all possible emails for said customer

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following input table

| email1 | email2 | email3 | email4 | email5 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B |  |  |  | 2023-01-01 |
| A | B |  |  |  | 2023-01-01 |
| B | C | A |  |  | 2023-01-02 |
| A | B | C |  |  | 2023-01-03 |
| X | Y |  |  |  | 2023-01-01 |
| X | Y |  |  |  | 2023-01-01 |
| Y | X |  |  |  | 2023-01-01 |

How do I get the following output table?

| email1 | email2 | email3 | email4 | email5 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |  |  | 2023-01-01 |
| A | B | C |  |  | 2023-01-01 |
| A | B | C |  |  | 2023-01-02 |
| A | B | C |  |  | 2023-01-03 |
| X | Y |  |  |  | 2023-01-01 |
| X | Y |  |  |  | 2023-01-01 |
| X | Y |  |  |  | 2023-01-01 |

Problem is I want to identify that first 4 rows are the same customer, and the last 3 rows are the same customer and have the same number of rows in the output table as in the input table. I have no customer identifier.
Rows 1-4 now all have A,B,C as emails, and Rows 5-7 has X,Y as emails

Basically I want to be able to tag all emails to the same customers, as long as at least one email is matching between the rows. and there will only be 5 emails ,maximum.

For example, rows 1-4 are the same customer, because the emails A and B are are part of all 4 rows. Similarly, in the last three rows, the customers have the same emails X and Y, just re arranged

I simply do not know how to approach this problem at all

Comment: What should happen if there is another row with emails `X`, `Y` and `A`? Or do they never overlap?

Comment: @tobifasc, No, that overlap would never happen

Comment: does the customer details reside in another table?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: No the customer details are not there anywhere else @Blip

Comment: I deleted my answer, because it was not enough to handle cases like (A, B), (B, C), (C, D), (D, E). I think some recursion would be needed here, but maybe others have better ideas.

Comment: @PonderStibbons yes, I was just checking them for such cases and they would not be handled, but thanks for the initial inputs, I appreciate it!